# How to use a loop to chang attribute of item in array by async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

this is the base state.An array and an async function.

```
let arr1 = [{num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}]

function asyncFunWithPromise(index) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(index)
      return index;
    }, 500);
  })
}
```

I expect to get something like this.

```
[ { num: 1, result: 0 }, { num: 2, result: 1 }, { num: 3, result: 2 } ]
```

the function below works, but I don't know when all of these async function would finish.

```
arr1.forEach(async (listItem, index) => {
  console.log(index)
  listItem.result = await asyncFunWithPromise(index)
});
console.log(arr1) // [ { num: 1 }, { num: 2 }, { num: 3 } ],async Func haven't finish
```

this works, but slow, like serial execution

```
(async () => {
  for (let index = 0; index < arr1.length; index++) {
    console.log(index)
    const currentItem = arr1[index];
    currentItem.result = await asyncFunWithPromise(currentItem.num)
  }
})()
```

This is my final solution with forEach, but it looks ugly.

```
let heighEfficiency = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const promiseArr = []
    arr1.forEach(async (listItem, index) => {
      promiseArr.push(asyncFunWithPromise(index))
      listItem.result = await promiseArr[index]
    });
    Promise.all(promiseArr).then(() => {
      resolve()
    }).catch(() => {
      reject()
    })
  })
}

heighEfficiency().then(() => {
  console.log(arr1)
})
```

This is another way ,using Promise.all and Array.map, I have no idea if this is a good approach.

```
const functionWithPromise = item => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      item.result = item.num + ':async done'
      resolve(item)
      return;
    }, 500);
  })
}

const getData = () => {
  return Promise.all(arr1.map(item => functionWithPromise(item)))
}

getData().then(data => {
  console.log(data) // get a new array here
})
```

Can any one share your solution?

Comment: Your lower code looks very nearly perfect to me. I wouldn't do anything fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0):

If we can return the new array, with updated attribute. We can use a functional approach

```
let arr = [ { num: 1, result: 0 }, { num: 2, result: 1 }, { num: 3, result: 2 } ];

arr = await Promise.all(arr.map(async i => {
 // ... do async logic in here
 return { ...i, result: 'async done'}
})
```